# Get complete file path from an array

Tags: php, arrays, file, recursion, directory

I have this array (which comes from a specific function : list and filter files of a directory on extension) :

```
Array
(
    [Dir_test] = Array
        (
            [dir_client] = Array
                (
                    [0] = index.html
                )

            [0] = index.html
        )
)
```

And I would like to get something like. Note : The directory could have way more subdirs.

```
Array
(
    [0] = Dir_test/dir_client/index.html
    [1] = Dir_test/index.html
)
```

Thx for your help ;)

Comment: PHP has an `is_array` function that might be helpful.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input data looks like this:

```
$arr = array(
    'Dir_test' => array (
        'dir_client' => array (
            0 => 'index.html'
        ),

        0 => 'index.html'
    )
);
```

The easiest solution is a recursive one, something like:

```
function add_dir($dir) {
    global $dirs;

    $dirs[] = $dir;
}

// pathsofar should always end in '/'
function process_dir($dirarray, $pathsofar) {
    foreach ($dirarray as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            process_dir($value, $pathsofar . $key . '/');
        } else {
            add_dir($pathsofar . $value);
        }
    }
}

process_dir($arr, '');

print_r($dirs);
```

Running it:

```
$ php arr2.php
Array
(
    [0] => Dir_test/dir_client/index.html
    [1] => Dir_test/index.html
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_walk_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) function

Answer (score 0):

Write a recursive function that takes an array and a string as arguments and returns and calls itself on every key of the array that holds itself an array.